# 403 error on moving codeigniter to live server

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-403

I have a Codeigniter site that works fine on my local XAMPP server, but now I've moved it to shared hosting I get a 403 forbidden error when I click on any link. The homepage displays fine, but any page with a slug produces the 403 error. E.g.

```
http://xxxxxxxxxxx/~test/
```

works fine

```
http://xxxxxxxxxxx/~test/about-us
```

produces the 403 error.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601263/403-error-when-moving-codeigniter-app-from-localhost-to-qa-server), but my application folder and its subfolders and files already all have permissions of 755.

My Base Url is set to

```
http://xxxxxxxxxxx/~test/
```

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|static)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

EDIT: If it makes a difference, I should say that I modified the core router.php (I know it's better to create my own MY_router.php, but anyway) to allow hyphens in the URL:

```
$segments = $this->_validate_request(str_replace('-','_',$segments));
```

but I tried changing it back to

```
$segments = $this->_validate_request($segments);
```

and it made no difference.

EDIT 2:

Another update. It works with URLs like this:

```
http://xxxxxxxxxx/~test/about-us/consultancy
```

just not with this

```
http://xxxxxxxxxx/~test/about-us
```

although this *does* work:

```
http://xxxxxxxxxx/~test/about-us/
```

Comment: Does http://example.com/~test/index.php/about-us work?

Comment: No, that produces the same error.

Comment: Where is the codeigniter installation? In html/index.php or html/~test/index.php (where html is the webserver root)?

Comment: This could be the root (no pun intended) of the problem. It's in public_html (the webserver root). The URL is currently http://123.456.789.0/~test/ which the hosting company say is until the actual domain name is configured.

Comment: Does `example.com/~test/index.php` have the same problem? Or is this the homepage you were referring to?

Comment: No, that shows the homepage. That works fine, as does example.com/~test/. It's just when I put a slug after that that the 403 error appears.

Comment: What happens if you add `RewriteBase /~test/` below `RewriteEngine on` in htaccess?

Comment: Thanks for your persistence! I've just tried that, and it doesn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Hrm. The only other thing I can think is that `.htaccess` isn't allowed (but the full url's with index.php should still work). Can you access logs? Either apache or CI?

Comment: The CI log only contains some 404 errors for missing images, which I've since restored. The server log contains several errors like this:  Symbolic link check failed: [/home/test/public_html/about-us], link owner does not match owner of link target.

Comment: stormdrain, if you still have time to follow this, please see my latest edit above, it looks like i'm getting somewhere...

Comment: Strange. See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14243157/183254